# android constraintLayout how to vertical attach to items above which may not visible

Tags: android-constraintlayout

Having a few items above the last row,  and they may all not visible or someone still visible.

Here is how they vertically aligned:

[content_part - 'Lorem ipsum...']

[media_image - RED BLOCK - has `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/content_part"`]

[quoted_view - IMG - has `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/media_image"`]

[comment - TEXTVIEW ROW - has `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoted_view"`]

when the `quoted_view` is visible, the `comment` button row is fine (both landscape and portrait):

[image]

but when the `quoted_view` is NOT visible in landscape the `comment` row is not displayed right

[image]

although in portrait mode it seems fine

[image]

How to vertically align to above items which may not visible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="52dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="re-tweet werwer wer we rwe r wer " />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />
    <!-- -->


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_part"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/media_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scaleType="matrix"

        android:visibility="visible"

        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,15:3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/content_part"
        app:layout_goneMarginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/quoted_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/media_image"
        app:layout_goneMarginBottom="8dp"

        android:visibility="gone">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <!-- quoted -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/response"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoted_view"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/response"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/like"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/comment"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/response"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#20000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**update:**

adding `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/comment"` to `android:id="@+id/view"` seems fixed it.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#20000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/comment" />
```

But not really understand why it has to have this constrain, the `android:id="@+id/comment"` already has constrain `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"`.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/response"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoted_view"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,15:3"` for `media_image` with a `0dp` height and `0dp` width, *ConstraintLayout* will maximize the width of the view and constrain the height of the view such that the resulting aspect ratio is 15:3 (5 x as wide as the height.)

So, given a screen width of, say, `500dp` the width of `media_image` will become `500dp` and the height will be `100dp`. So, what happens when the actual height of the screen is something less than `100dp` plus the height of the *TextViews*? You will see your problem. (Screen sizes are for example and do not reflect actual screen dimensions that I am aware of.)

The question now depends upon what you want to happen with the layout when the dimensions don't quite work as you have things laid out now.

Comment: thanks @Cheticamp. What you said make sense. But I think in that case the last "comment" row should be pushed out of screen instead of float on top of the `media_image`, since `media_image` attaches to bottom of the `content_part`; `quoted_view` attaches to bottom of the `media_image`; `comment row` attaches to the bottom of the `quoted_view`.  when  the `quoted_view` is not visible, the `comment row` should still be placed under `media_image`, why it is float on top of it?

Comment: looked at the layout again, by @Cheticamp's hint, that this caused by the lowest 'view' which is bottom attached to `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` . while the two textView have `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"`, so they are show up on top of the `media_image`.

Comment: hmm, but the root `android:id="@+id/container"` has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` so the last view `"@+id/view"` should grow out of the screen, right?